# run local instance of elastic search with docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm following the instructions here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html
and only need one elastic search instance. When I run `docker-compose up` I get an error saying `The compose file docker-compose.yml is invalid because Unsupported config option for services.volumes: 'esdata1'`

What am I doing wrong?

My docker-compose file

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have missed the top-level `volumes` section towards the end of the sample file given here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-prod-cluster-composefile).

Docker Compose v2 reference also specifies this requirement - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes-volumedriver

Excerpt from the above link:
`For version 2 files, named volumes need to be specified with the top-level volumes key.`